# ActiveAdmin: how to add formatter to any column with specific name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a helper called `ip_with_location` which translates `10.10.10.10` to `10.10.10.10 - DE, Berlin` form.

Usage example:

```
index do
  ...
  column :ip do |r|
    ip_with_location(r.ip)
  end
end
```

**The questions is:** Is there a way to automatically format column value with my custom helper?

So I would just write `column :ip` instead.

Overwriting `ip` getter on model level would not be an option, cause i want such format only in `ActiveAdmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin don't has a build in way for that.

1. You can build a `ip_with_location` method on your model an use this in the Admin
2. You can us a [Decorator](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/11-decorators.md)
3. You can write a 'template'

   ```
   # app/admin/ip_column.rb
   require "active_admin/views/index_as_table"
   module ActiveAdmin
     module Views
       class IndexAsTable < ActiveAdmin::Component
         class IndexTableFor < ::ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor
           def ip_column
             column :ip do |r|
               ip_with_location(r.ip)
             end
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end

   # app/admin/user.rb
   require "ip_column"
   index do
     id_column
     column :name
     ip_column
   end
   ```

Comment: What if I have to apply same decorator for ip thing in mutilple models but column name is not exactly ip in all models e.g in one model column is ip but in another ip_address?